# Returning the first number of a parameter in Python

Tags: python

Edit: Thank you guys for your help, but I had trouble applying it to my actual problem. I was trying to get a general idea of how to do a similar problem to one I was assigned, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

So, my functions is going to take two parameters, both of which are numbers. If the first parameter is equal to 0, I have to set it to the first number that occurs in the second parameter.

so like if

> > > num_call(0, 23)

I would have to return a 2.

Any tips on how to do this? Or would the way you guys have been describing work?

Thanks so much

Comment: `"Charger"[2]` == 'a'  Python strings are sub scriptable. Try `'Charger'[::-1]`

Answer (score 3):

You can access a string's individual characters by their position/index (note that they are **0-indexed**):

```
>>> s = "Charger"
>>> s[2]
'a'
```

If instead of a string you have a number, you can convert it to a string, and then use the same technique:

```
>>> i = 1234
>>> str(i)[2]
'3'
```

Comment: OK, what about if I have function thats parameter is a number and I wanted to take the third number of the number? Like 1145, and I get 4?

Comment: Typecast it.  str(number) will convert your number into an ASCII string ("1234" for example) from there, just do what Joao said.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your comments (function, words and numbers) have a look at following code:

```
def print_third_character(string):
    print str(string)[2]

print_third_character("Charger")
>>> a
print_third_character(1145)
>>> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer something like this

```
def return_third_character(string):
    ts = str(string)
    if len(ts) >= 3:
        return ts[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your edited question.

If your function call is num_call(0, 23) and you want to recall it with num_call(2, 3) use this code:

```
def num_call(first_parameter, second_parameter):
    if first_parameter == 0:
        num_call(int(str(second_parameter)[0]), int(str(second_parameter)[1:]))
```

if you just want to return the second parameter, if the first one is 0, use this code (note that it'll return the first argument, if first_argument is not 0):

```
def num_call(first_parameter, second_parameter):
    if first_parameter == 0:
        return int(str(second_parameter)[0])
    else:
        return first_parameter
```